# coffeescript can't find localStorage

Tags: macos, coffeescript, local-storage

I'm trying to teach myself coffeescript, but is falling short when trying to use localStorage.

```
$ coffee detail_view.coffee 
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
  at isLoggedIn (/Users/me/workspace/hero/html_client/detail_view.coffee:12:18, <js>:5:13)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/workspace/hero/html_client/detail_view.coffee:225:4, <js>:144:7)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/workspace/hero/html_client/detail_view.coffee:164:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

The line in detail_view.coffee is:

```
(localStorage.getItem("a_key") isnt null) and (localStorage.getItem("b_key") isnt null)
```

I've tried installing localstorage through npm, but it doesn't help.
i.e.

```
$ sudo npm -g install localstorage
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/localstorage
npm http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/localstorage
localStorage@1.0.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/localStorage

$ echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/localStorage:$PATH' >> ~/.profile
$ source ~/.profile
$ coffee detail_view.coffee 
ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
  at isLoggedIn (/Users/me/workspace/hero/html_client/detail_view.coffee:12:18, <js>:5:13)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/workspace/hero/html_client/detail_view.coffee:225:4, <js>:144:7)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/me/workspace/hero/html_client/detail_view.coffee:164:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` is a feature provided by the web browser.  In node.js it doesn't exist.  Which means if you reference `localStorage` in a script ran by node.js you will get errors.

And even if you install the `localStorage` npm module you mention, you need to require it to use it.

```
localStorage = require('localStorage')
localStorage.getItem 'a_key'
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. Where can I check which techs aren't known my Node and how to add them? I now get a similar problem for 'window'. window = require('window') doesn't work...

Comment: I'm not aware of any list, but really if it's browser related it's not going to be there.  `window` doesn't make sense in node.js, there is no window.  But you can use `global` in node.js for creating globals variables in the same way you would use `window` in a browser.  Keep [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/) open in your browser.  If it's not in there, it doesn't exist.